# How to read spaced string with get line() from a file?

Tags: c++

I want to read a name like "Penelope Pasaft" all together from a file and save it to a variable "person". I have understood that I have to use the get line(file, person). But I have a problem doing it because I want also to read other variables before. 
Imagine a .txt like:

---

1

+546343864246

Penelope Pasaft

---

So here is the code:

```
typedef struct {

    string number; //I use string because it is an alphanumeric cellphone number 
    string person;
    int identifier;
} cellphone;

ifstream entry;

entry.open(fileName.c_str());

cellphone c[10];

int j=0;

    if(entry)
    {
        cout << "The file has been successfully opened\n\n";
        while(!entry.eof())
        {
            entry >> c[j].identifier >> c[j].number;
            getline(entry,c[j].person);

            cout << "Start: " << c[j].identifier << "\nNumber: " <<
                c[j].number << "\nPerson: " << c[j].person << endl << endl;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Well the problem I have it's that it doesn't seem to print or save me any data to the variable c[j].person

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your input file has empty lines in it.

If you use `cin >>` only, it will work OK because `>>` operator skips blank chars (but stops at blank chars, as you noted: can't have it all)

On the other hand, `getline` will read the line, even if it's blank.

I propose the following standalone code slightly modified from yours: note the loop until end of file or non-blank line.
(note: it there are spaces only in the line, it will fail)

I also replaced array by a vector, resized on the fly (more C++-ish)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {

    string number; //I use string because it is an alphanumeric cellphone number 
    string person;
    int identifier;
} cellphone;


int main()
{

ifstream entry;
string fileName = "file.txt";
entry.open(fileName.c_str());

vector<cellphone> c;

cellphone current;

int j=0;

    if(entry)
    {
        cout << "The file has been successfully opened\n\n";
        while(!entry.eof())
        {
            entry >> current.identifier >> current.number;
            while(!entry.eof())
            {
            getline(entry,current.person);
            if (current.person!="") break;  // stops if non-blank line
            }
            c.push_back(current);

            cout << "Start: " << c[j].identifier << "\nNumber: " << c[j].number << "\nPerson: " << c[j].person <<endl<<endl;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
The file has been successfully opened

Start: 1
Number: +546343864246
Person: Penelope Pasaft
```